# Use API key for Google Plus API from Android app

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

Is it okay to use API key with Google Plus API from Android application?

"An API key (either a server key or a browser key) is a unique identifier that you generate using the Developers Console. Using an API key does not require user action or consent. API keys do not grant access to any account information, and are not used for authorization." (https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/?hl=en_US#usingkeys)

In my application I need to get public information about current user from his Google Plus profile. This is publicly available information such as first and last name, gender etc. It's not required to authorize the user or access any protected information. So one can just make a request to Google Plus API:

`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/<user ID>?key=<API key>`

and get the response. It works on Android.

However, the API key is "a server key" and, as I understand, is not recommended to use it in Android applications. For Android applications it's recommended to use Google Play Services library which doesn't require API key (instead the application package name and digest of the signing certificate should be added to list of allowed apps in developers console).

But if I use Google Play Services, it will show a dialog saying my application wants to get access to user's personal information. I want to avoid to show that dialog because the only my purpose is to fill input fields in my app with first and last name from Google Plus. And in fact I'm not able to access any other personal information using API key.

So, the question is:

- Given that using API key with Google Plus API for only requesting for public profile information technically works in my Android app, is it allowed to do so? Can it be considered as a violation of some policy?
- Maybe there is another way to get first and last name of current user from Google Plus profile in Android application? (Not the way with Google Play Services library)

Comment: Hey @Dmitry Trunin, I've submitted a bug report on this because neither the Android or iOS Key created in the credentials area, actually work for API calls.  If possible, could you star it there so that it might get the proper attention and maybe fixed?  URL: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=1206&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars